# C++ A star algorithm not finding target node

Tags: c++, algorithm, a-star

I'm trying to create an A star algorithm in c++.
However, the target node is never found. I know that the function is incomplete because the path is never updated but that is not relative to my problem.

I think I'm doing something wrong with the tentative G score  and the neighbor G score at `if (tentative_gScore <= neighbor_gScore)`

What am I doing wrong and how can I change it to get it working?

```
static double getScore(map::map_node* node, std::unordered_map<map::map_node*, double> map)
{
    for (auto& it : map) {
        if(it.first->node_id() == node->node_id()) {
            return it.second;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

static float heuristic(map::map_node& source, map::map_node& target)
{
    return std::fabs(source.location().x() - target.location().x()) + std::abs(source.location().y() - target.location().y());
}

double helper::getDistanceFromCurrentToNeighbor(math::vector2d current, math::vector2d neighbor)
{
    if (current.x() == neighbor.x())
    {
        return std::fabs(current.y() - neighbor.y());
    }
        
    return std::fabs(current.x() - neighbor.x());
}

std::pair<std::vector<map::map_node*>, double> helper::shortestPathToDist(map::map_node& source_node, map::map_node& target_node)
{
    std::vector<map::map_node*> path;
    std::unordered_map<map::map_node*, map::map_node*> visited;
    std::unordered_map<map::map_node*, double> gScore;
    std::unordered_map<map::map_node*, double> fScore;

    using scored_node = std::pair<double, map::map_node*>;
    auto cmp = [&target_node](scored_node& n1, scored_node& n2)
    {
        return n1.first > n2.first;
    };
    std::priority_queue<scored_node, std::vector<scored_node>, decltype(cmp)> queue(cmp);
    

    gScore.insert({&source_node, 0});
    fScore.insert({ &source_node, heuristic(source_node, target_node)});

    queue.push({ 0.0, &source_node });

    bool foundPath = false;

    while(!queue.empty())
    {
        auto shortest_path_scored_node = queue.top();
        auto shortest_path_node = shortest_path_scored_node.second;

        if (shortest_path_node->node_id() == target_node.node_id())
        {
            foundPath = true;
            break;
        }

        queue.pop();

        for (int i = 0; i < shortest_path_node->num_edges(); i++) {
            map::map_edge edge = (*shortest_path_node)[i];
            map::map_node* node_to = &edge.to();

            //double tentative_gScore = shortest_path_scored_node.first + static_cast<double>(edge.weight() * getDistanceFromCurrentToNeighbor(shortest_path_node->location(), node_to->location()));
            double tentative_gScore = getScore(shortest_path_node, gScore) + static_cast<double>(edge.weight() * getDistanceFromCurrentToNeighbor(shortest_path_node->location(), node_to->location()));
            double neighbor_gScore = getScore(node_to, gScore);

            if (tentative_gScore <= neighbor_gScore)
            {
                visited.insert({node_to, shortest_path_node});
                gScore.insert({node_to, tentative_gScore });
                fScore.insert({node_to, neighbor_gScore + heuristic(*shortest_path_node, *node_to) });

                queue.push({ tentative_gScore, node_to });
            }
        }
    }


    
    return std::make_pair<>(path, 0);
}
```

Edit: I added the structures of the objects being used:
Map node:

```
struct map_node_info {
  /*! \brief The kind of tile.

    This could for instance convey information about the type of area:
    grassland, or desert or water.
  */
  char kind;
};

using map_graph = kmint::graph::basic_graph<map_node_info>;
using map_node = kmint::graph::basic_node<map_node_info>;
using map_edge = kmint::graph::basic_edge<map_node_info>;

template <typename NodeInfo> class basic_node {

public:
  using info_type = NodeInfo;
  //! The associated edge type for this node
  using edge_type = basic_edge<NodeInfo>;
  using container = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<edge_type>>;
  using iterator =
      kmint::util::wrapped_iterator<edge_type, typename container::iterator>;
  using const_iterator =
      kmint::util::wrapped_iterator<const edge_type,
                                    typename container::const_iterator>;
  basic_node(basic_node const &) = delete;
  basic_node(basic_node &&) noexcept = default;
  basic_node &operator=(basic_node const &) = delete;
  basic_node &operator=(basic_node &&) noexcept = default;
  ~basic_node() = default;

  NodeInfo &node_info() noexcept { return node_info_; }
  NodeInfo const &node_info() const noexcept { return node_info_; }

  kmint::math::vector2d location() const noexcept { return location_; }
  void add_edge(basic_node &to, float weight) {
    edges_.push_back(std::make_unique<edge_type>(*this, to, weight));
  }
  const_iterator begin() const noexcept {
    return {edges_.begin(), util::deref_unique_ptr_const<edge_type>};
  }
  const_iterator end() const noexcept {
    return {edges_.end(), util::deref_unique_ptr_const<edge_type>};
  }
  const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept {
    return {edges_.begin(), util::deref_unique_ptr_const<edge_type>};
  }
  const_iterator cend() const noexcept {
    return {edges_.end(), util::deref_unique_ptr_const<edge_type>};
  }
  iterator begin() noexcept {
    return {edges_.begin(), util::deref_unique_ptr<edge_type>};
  }
  iterator end() noexcept {
    return {edges_.end(), util::deref_unique_ptr<edge_type>};
  }
  edge_type const &operator[](std::size_t index) const noexcept {
    return *edges_[index];
  }
  edge_type &operator[](std::size_t index) noexcept { return *edges_[index]; }
  std::size_t num_edges() const noexcept { return edges_.size(); }
  std::size_t node_id() const noexcept { return node_id_; }
  /*!
   * Returns whether this node was tagged
   *
   * A node is considered to be tagged if its tag is unequal to node_tag::normal
   *
   * \return Whether the node is tagged or not
   */
  [[deprecated]] bool tagged() const noexcept {
    return tag_ != node_tag::normal;
  }
  /*!
   * Sets the tagged state of a node
   *
   * This function is provided solely for backwards compatibility reasons.
   * Passing false will set this node's tag to node_tag::normal. Passing true
   * will set this node's tag to node_tag::visisted
   *
   */
  [[deprecated]] void tagged(bool t) noexcept {
    tag_ = t ? node_tag::visited : node_tag::normal;
  }
  /*!
   * \return this node's tag
   */
  node_tag tag() const noexcept { return tag_; };
  /*!
   * Changes this node's tag.
   * \param t the tag to assign to this node.
   */
  void tag(node_tag t) noexcept { tag_ = t; };

  friend class basic_graph<NodeInfo>;

private:
  explicit basic_node(std::size_t id, math::vector2d loc) noexcept(
      std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<NodeInfo>::value)
      : node_id_{id}, location_{loc} {};
  basic_node(std::size_t id, math::vector2d loc, NodeInfo const &info) noexcept(
      std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<NodeInfo>::value)
      : node_id_{id}, location_{loc}, node_info_{info} {};
  basic_node(std::size_t id, math::vector2d loc, NodeInfo &&info) noexcept(
      std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<NodeInfo>::value)
      : node_id_{id}, location_{loc}, node_info_{std::move(info)} {};

  std::size_t node_id_;
  kmint::math::vector2d location_;
  NodeInfo node_info_;
  node_tag tag_{node_tag::normal};
  container edges_{};
};
```

Edge:

```
template <typename NodeInfo> class basic_edge {
public:
  using node_type = basic_node<NodeInfo>;
  //! Construct a directed edge
  /*! 
    Constructs a directed edge from \a from to \a to. 

    \param from the starting point of the edge
    \param to the destination of the edge
    \param weight an optional weight (cost) associated with the edge (defaults to \a 1.0)
   */
  basic_edge(node_type &from, node_type &to, float weight = 1.0f)
      : from_{&from}, to_{&to}, weight_{weight} {}
  //! Returns a const reference to the destination node
  node_type const &to() const noexcept { return *to_; }
  //! Returns a reference to the destination node
  node_type &to() noexcept { return *to_; }
  //! Returns a const reference to the starting node
  node_type const &from() const noexcept { return *from_; }
  //! Returns a reference to the starting node
  node_type &from() noexcept { return *from_; }
  //! Returns the weight associated with this edge
  float weight() const noexcept { return weight_; }

private:
  node_type *from_;
  node_type *to_;
  float weight_;
};
```

Edit 2: Changed the search function to make it return a path and added a get element by key function to retrieve element from map when found or return the max integer

```
template <template<class, class, class...> class C, typename K, typename V, typename... Args>
V GetWithDef(const C<K, V, Args...>& m, K const& key)
{
    typename C<K, V, Args...>::const_iterator it = m.find(key);
    if (it == m.end())
        return INT32_MAX;
    return it->second;
}
```

```
std::pair<std::vector<map::map_node*>, double> helper::shortestPathToDist(map::map_node& source_node, map::map_node& target_node)
{
    std::vector<map::map_node*> path;
    std::unordered_map<map::map_node*, map::map_node*> visited;
    std::unordered_map<map::map_node*, double> gScore;
    std::unordered_map<map::map_node*, double> fScore;

    using scored_node = std::pair<double, map::map_node*>;
    auto cmp = [&target_node](scored_node& n1, scored_node& n2)
    {
        return n1.first > n2.first;
    };
    std::priority_queue<scored_node, std::vector<scored_node>, decltype(cmp)> queue(cmp);
    

    gScore.insert({&source_node, 0});
    fScore.insert({ &source_node, heuristic(source_node, target_node)});

    queue.push({ 0.0, &source_node });

    bool foundPath = false;

    while(!queue.empty())
    {
        auto shortest_path_scored_node = queue.top();
        auto shortest_path_node = shortest_path_scored_node.second;

        if (shortest_path_node->node_id() == target_node.node_id())
        {
            foundPath = true;
            break;
        }

        queue.pop();

        for (int i = 0; i < shortest_path_node->num_edges(); i++) {
            map::map_edge edge = (*shortest_path_node)[i];
            map::map_node* node_to = &edge.to();

            double tentative_gScore = GetWithDef(gScore, shortest_path_node); + static_cast<double>(edge.weight() * getDistanceFromCurrentToNeighbor(shortest_path_node->location(), node_to->location()));
            double neighbor_gScore = GetWithDef(gScore, node_to);

            if (tentative_gScore <= neighbor_gScore)
            {
                visited.insert({node_to, shortest_path_node});
                gScore.insert({node_to, tentative_gScore });
                fScore.insert({node_to, neighbor_gScore + heuristic(*shortest_path_node, *node_to) });

                queue.push({ tentative_gScore, node_to });
            }
        }
    }

    if (!foundPath)
    {
        return {};
    }

    map::map_node* current = &target_node;
    while (current)
    {
        path.push_back(current);
        current = visited[current];
    }
    std::reverse(path.begin(), path.end());
    
    return std::make_pair<>(path, queue.top().first);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger? `getScore` returns zero (or even worse `NULL`) for every node not in the `map`. Since `gScore` only contains one element at the beginning and distances are probably non-negative. The body of the if-statement is never executed. 
Note: There are also several other problems with this code and the way this question is formed, e. g. why are you checking IDs and deal with pointers?

Comment: Yes I used the debugger and that I should change the scores, hence I ask for help. I'm checking ID's to see if the target node is reached. How would I need to form the question and code if it's not correct according to you?

Comment: You never use `visited`. (And `node_to` is not a pointer in your graph, and will become invalid at the end of the iteration. Use either id's or addresses for identification, don't mix them.)

Comment: @molbdnilo How is `node_to` not a pointer in my graph? it's literally the node next to the current shortest_path_node or am I missing something completely?

Comment: Well, it could be a pointer in your graph, depending on what `to()` returns a reference to.

Comment: @molbdnilo It's meant to be a pointer to an object for that single for loop iteration since the next iteration you will get a different edge. I'm not sure how this resembles to my actual problem?

Comment: The problem is, your code does not qualify as a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can just stare at the code and hope to find a mistake. You might want to add the definitions of your graph structure so that can see if some pointers might be invalidated as molbdnilo assumes and we can test our own suggestions locally before we post a comment. To answer your question about scores—check the [Pseudocode on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode). It makes it very clear that the default value is supposed to be very large.

Comment: You're storing that pointer in your tables, and dereferencing it after the iteration ends has undefined behaviour. (And it's most likely going to have the same numerical value in each iteration.)

Comment: I added the structures of map_node and map_edge. I know `neighbor_gScore` will always be 0 since it's not in the map but I tried multiple things and none worked besides getting the edges of the source node in the queue and just left that piece of code there.

Comment: The mixture of pointers, reference, and values, and the complexity of your edge and node classes make this code very hard to follow and reason about. (In my opinion, premature generalization is a special case of premature optimization but along a different dimension. Make it work first, then generalize.)

Comment: @molbdnilo The node and edge classes can't be changed because they come from a framework I have to use. I edited the post and changed the tentative G scores with using the maximum integer value. This seems to work for now. Is this a valid fix?

Comment: The G score should be the distance (aka, difference) from the parent plus the parent's G. See https://github.com/BrannonKing/Kts.Astar/blob/master/Kts.AStar/SearchNodeBase.cs